# Webworks Google map is frozen

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am pretty new to this whole WebWorks stuff (Just started playing around with it today, getting ready for a local blackberry hackathon) and i decided to learn it by action with the google maps api to generate content for me to play with, as well as considering a WebWorks port of a maps app i'm working on for Android.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"" />
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SNIP&sensor=true&language=es&region=CO">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initializeMap()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html { 
    height: 100% 
}

body { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

#map_canvas { 
    height: 100% 
}
```

And the JS:

```
function initializeMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.199383, -75.578980),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Now my question is: Why doesn't clicking or dragging the map on the Ripple emulator work? [WebWorks BB10] It works wonders on chrome, i can pan, zoom and the markers get placed when i click them.

Thanks.

**Edit**
The map renders fine on Ripple, but the map itself won't work, nothing happens if i click or drag around with the mouse. The Satellite, Map and zoom buttons do work though

Answer (score 0):

Clicking or dragging the map on the Ripple emulator may not work for a couple of reasons:

1. There is a runtime error happening and something within the Google
   Maps is failing.  Try opening Web Inspector (right click on map in
   Ripple and select "Inspect Element") to see if there are any run
   time errors.  It may explain why certain behavior is not working as
   expected.
2. Touch events may not be handled correctly.  Try opening Web Inspector (right click on  map in Ripple and select "Inspect Element"). Then open the settings (gear in bottom right corner) and select the "Overrides" tab.  Make sure that the "Emulate touch events" checkbox is enabled.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There was a runtime error trying to parse an empty string as JSON, fixed it with a status code check on the response of the request (And according to http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Uncaught-SyntaxError-Unexpected-end-of-input-with-Webworks-1-0-2/td-p/1959793 it is purely cosmetic). Enabling that override seems to have frozen the map completely, now not even the map buttons will work. sadface.png

Comment: Very odd.  I'm not sure why the touch events are not responding.  This article was written to compare different Mapping libraries, it may be of interest? http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/05/lightweight-maps-for-mobile-part-1/

Comment: I will try the bing maps library and report back, thanks for that awesome link